# stuck on loading made a minor change to App.js

Tags: reactjs

I have this basic App.js file,

```
import './App.css';

function Header(){
return(
   <Header>
      <h1>hey there</h1>
   </Header>
 );
}


function App() {
return (
    <div className="App">
       <Header />
       <h2>Main</h2>
       <h3>Footer</h3>
    </div>
 );
}

export default App;
```

The site was loading fine before I created the Header function and put it in app. But now it's stuck on loading, it's not showing anything on the page.

Comment: Your `Header` functional component renders a `Header` functional component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you meant to use html `header` tag like this:

```
function Header() {
  return (
    <header>
      <h1>hey there</h1>
    </header>
  );
}
```